# Bootstrapping data at application startup with Simperium

Tags: simperium

As someone that experienced the pain of iCloud while trying to prototype iCloud enabling one of our CoreData apps, Simperium looks very promising, but I'm interested in seeing how it handles some of the sharp edges.

One issue I came across was how to gracefully handle bootstrapping data when the application starts up.  The first time a user launches our app, we will load some default data into our CoreData database.  If a user launches the app first on the iPhone and then later on the iPad, they will end up getting the bootstrap data duplicated on both devices because of syncing.  With iCloud, the solution was to hook into the iCloud merge process.

How would I handle this with Simperium?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple ways to do this.

You can hardcode the `simperiumKey` for each seeded object. For example, in a notes app, if every new user gets a welcome note, you can locally create that note with the `simperiumKey` of `welcomeNote`. This will ensure that only one welcome note will ever exist in that user's account (on any device). With this approach, there can be some redundant data transfer, so it's best if there's not a large amount of seeded data. On the other hand, this approach is good if you want data to be immediately available to new users even if they're offline when they first launch your app.

With Simperium, you also have the option to use a server process. You can seed new user accounts with data by using a Python or Ruby listener that runs some code when accounts are created. This is a good approach if there's a large amount of data, but has the disadvantage that users need to be online before the seeded data will transfer (and of course the transfer itself will take some time).

There are subtleties with these approaches. With the first approach, using the `welcomeNote` example, if your user deletes the `welcomeNote` and subsequently reinstalls your app in the future, the `welcomeNote` will get resurrected (but never duplicated) because it's being created locally. This is often acceptable. With the second approach, the `welcomeNote` would be seeded once and only once, so it will never get resurrected even if your app is reinstalled.